# How do memory gets shared in union

Tags: c, unions

for following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union share
{
    int num;
    char str[3];
}share1;

int main()
{
    strcpy(share1.str,"ab");
    printf("str is %s and num is %d", share1.str, share1.num );
    return 0;
}
```

I get output as "str is ab and num is 25185".
str is printed as it is but how do I get 25185.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Here we're usually dealing with problems that can't be solved by reading a simple tutorial about the topic. Please read about `union` in C.

Answer (score 1):

Unions overlap in  memory. That means the 2 bytes representing your `int` share the same memory location as the first 2 chars (bytes) of your string. Changing the characters automatically changes the int, since by definition they're the SAME thing... just being treated differently because you can access those two bytes as a char OR an int.

```
a -> 0x61
b -> 0x62

25185 -> 0x6261
              ^--- a
            ^----- b
```

Answer (score 1):

the actual hex coding for "ab" is: 0x616200

Of importance is that the instance of the union is in file global space
so the memory is 'pre-set' to all 0x00.

depending on the architecture, (little or big Endian) that value
"ab" will be read as either:

```
0x00006261 or as 0x61620000
```

given the small magnitude of the printed number, it is obvious that
the integer representation is 0x00006261. (little Endian)

0x00006261 (hex) is 25185 (decimal)